# Average computational graph with pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, out-of-memory

I'am writting to due  because I cope with the following situation: during training, I need a for loop in pytorch's forward function. Hereafter a sample of my code:

```
def forward(self, input_sinogram, sos):
    [variables declaration...]
    # stack = torch.zeros(batch_size, self.nb_elements * self.nb_elements, 
    for tx_id in range(0, self.nb_elements, self.decimation_factor):
      [variables declaration...]
      ima = self.netFeaturesExtractor(ima)
      stack[:, id_stack, :, :] = ima
      id_stack += 1
```

Doing that, pytorch computed build the computational graph for each iteration, and fill the memory. If there are too many iterations, it takes up too much memory. Thus I tried the following implementation:

```
def forward(self, input_sinogram, sos):
    [variables declaration...]
    # stack = torch.zeros(batch_size, self.nb_elements * self.nb_elements, 
    for tx_id in range(0, self.nb_elements, self.decimation_factor):
       if tx_id == self.id_no_frz:
          self.auto_grad(True)
       else:
          self.auto_grad(False)
       [variables declaration...]
       ima = self.netFeaturesExtractor(ima)
       stack[:, id_stack, :, :] = ima
       id_stack += 1

def auto_grad(self, freeze):
    """ Freeze network."""

    for param in self.netFeaturesExtractor.parameters():
      param.requires_grad = freeze
```

My idea was to build a computational graph only for some iterations. In practice it doesn't work, the model converges after a few epochs.

I a wonder if it is possible to average the computational graph of each iteration? That way, the backpropagation would be faster and take all the data into account. It would also avoid memory issues. I didn't find anything on this topic.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know what a "computational graph" is?

Comment: Hi Evan

I know what is a computational graph.

Please tell if I'm wrong: In my situation, pytorch produces n computational graphs. Those n-graphs are identical, but have different values. I want to average these values to produce a unique graph, which would be used during backpropagation. In other words, I'm looking for "graph accumulation" such as pytorch is able to do for "gradient accumulation". Does this make sense?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If think there is some confusion as to what a "computation graph" is in PyTorch. This in fact an concept to formalise the process of doing inferences on a set of operators and backpropagating through it. Think of it as the flow of operations that have been performed from the inputs and parameters to output the different results of your model.

This graph is not saved in memory in memory at a, specific location. Instead it is built on the fly, after every operation PyTorch caches some tensors and introduces callback functions on those tensor nodes in order to perform gradient computation on them later on. That callback function is in the form of the `torch.Tensor.grad_fn` attribute. The point of this design is to make it scale and not have to rely on a precomputed graph before doing inference.

Even if you did have access to this kind of graph I am not sure the "graph accumulation" process is clear to you. Keep in mind that at this point, no propagation operation has been performed on the nodes of that model. **What would you be doing with those nodes?**

You can only do such operations on gradients or weights themselves:

- *gradient accumulation* is allowing the weights to accumulate gradients over several inference iterations before updating those weights and clearing the gradient caches.
- *weight average* this comes into [model ensembling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) whereby you are averaging weight values of your model across multiple trainings.